# Display multiple divs depending on value amount, i.e value 3, display 3 divs

Tags: php, jquery, html

I'm trying to display some divs, the amount of divs that are displayed depends on how many have values.

So, i've managed to echo the amount of divs that have values, now I need to know how to display that amount depending on the value.

i.e if there are 3 values, it should show 3 divs

Any ideas?

Here's some code.

```
<?php
$count=count($hero_options);
$totalimg=$count-1;
for($i=1;$i<=$totalimg;$i++){
    if( isset( $hero_options['upload_image_link_'.$i.''] ) && $hero_options[ 'upload_image_link_'.$i.'' ] ) {
        $html = '<li><span>Image '.$i.'</span></li>';
        $html .= '<li><span>Image '.$i.'</span></li>';
    }
}
echo $html;
?>
```

Final working code below.

```
<?php
$count=count($hero_options);
$totalimg=$count-1;
$html = '<li><span>Image '.$i.'</span></li>';
for($i=1;$i<=$totalimg;$i++){
    if( isset( $hero_options['upload_image_link_'.$i.''] ) && $hero_options[ 'upload_image_link_'.$i.'' ] ) {
        echo $html;
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: add some code to your question.

Comment: Have you tried a `for` loop?

Comment: yes, that's how i'm getting the value amount, i just don't know how to convert that to show the amount of divs shown, I've now added my code to the post.

Comment: You're reinitializing the $html variable in each run through the for loop. Try initializing that outside the for loop, appending the <li> you want to it and then echoing it.

Comment: @lascort Thanks for the input but I don't understand, it's taken me ages to get to this point as i'm still very much a learner.

Comment: Never mind I figured it out thanks. i've pasted the code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're resetting the value of `$html` everytime you go through the for loop. This should work for you.

```
<?php
$count=count($hero_options);
$totalimg=$count-1;
$html = "";
for($i=1;$i<=$totalimg;$i++){
    if( isset( $hero_options['upload_image_link_'.$i.''] ) && $hero_options[ 'upload_image_link_'.$i.'' ] ) {
        $html .= '<li><span>Image '.$i.'</span></li>';
    }
}
echo $html;
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, works perfect. How can I do the same with a stylesheet. i.e. span { background: url(<?php echo $hero_options['upload_image_link_2']; ?>);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;}

Comment: 2 will depend on the value in the database.

Comment: Just append the style to it... instead of $html.='<li>...</li>' use $html.='<li><span style="background:'.$myBackground.'">'.$i.'</span></li>'...

Comment: Thanks, can't believe i didn't think of that.